# JSON string character

Tags: java, javascript, json

I have these

`JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();`

`obj.put("id","foo");`

My id is `string`. What characters can I put instead of foo? Can I put these `"\!@#$%^&*()'"` ?

Comment: Could you rephrase the question, as a native English speaker I have absolutely no clue what your question is

Comment: 1) The 'fragment' you show is not valid JSON. 2) Your question lacks a considerable amount of detail that is required in order to provide an answer - aka, what JSON framework are you using, how are you generating the main JSON message, ***what have you tried*** and what problems are you running into.

Comment: Is this [Java or JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)? Unless there's a lot more detail to this question that you're not telling us about, one of those tags has to go...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://www.json.org/ under **string**. You can use:

> Any UNICODE character except " or \ or control character

Comment: That diagram has branches. You can have other characters.

Comment: Ah true, the "\" escaped characters. Sorry, still on first coffee of the day.